# How to monitor produced energy?

Tags: current, solar-cell, energy, monitor

I want to monitor energy produced by 250W solar panel. But I need some hints. Does anyone knows something? Is it possible using ACS758 chip or better I have to use current transformator?

Finally I plan to log all data and store to create annual report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Energy is the time integral of power and power is the terminal voltage produced by the solar panel multiplied by the current taken from the panel. So, if you monitor both voltage and current and do some math you get power. This can then be integrated to produce watt-seconds (joules).

Because your system is DC I would consider using a small series resistor in the current path, probably in the range of 10 milli-ohm. The voltage across it is proportional to current (via ohms law) and this can be easily amplified and fed into something like an arduino. The voltage can also be monitored and also fed into an arduino. The arduino could then multiply voltage and current to get power. The arduino could also time integrate power to get energy.

Comment: I'd rather use a hall current sensor. They can be as cheap as 10€ and the power dissipated is much lower, I think that solar panels have a low voltage, high current output so using a shunt might not be ideal. OT: see you in the finals!

Comment: @VladimirCravero ha ha the finals - the loser_finals LOL

Comment: Inquiring minds want to know - as they used to say -  what finals may these be?

Comment: World cup finals, no tests involved here

Comment: @RussellMcMahon NZ is more noted for the Rugby exploits so there's no need to worry you about the disgraces of the European soccer teams LOL.

Comment: I though maybe it's better idea measure current and voltage then calculate energy using Arduino. But I need also a voltage sensor and there is (as I know) unfortunately nothing like this available. How to measure voltage then?

Comment: Voltage is easy - just use a resistive potential divider to scale the maximum panel voltage to 5V and feed into the arduino. If max voltage is 25V then a 40k and 10k resistor reduce 25v to 5v suitable for the ADC on the arduino.

Comment: I found many nice videos on youtube regarding energy management solutions with Arduino.

Comment: I probably won't want to watch them.

Comment: Very helpful blog: http://www.256.co.uk